# Unable to locate element using UIScrollable and UISelector

Tags: java, appium, scrollable

I am using this code to select element

```
public static void swipe()
{

    MobileElement element = driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator(
                    "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().class(\"android.widget.ImageView\")).getChildByText("
                    + "new UiSelector().resourceId(\"com.spotify.music:id/title\"), \"UnderCover\")");

    //Perform the action on the element
    System.out.println(element.getText()); //This would print - Unblock Me FREE
}
```

and I am getting this as error

```
io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.UiSelectorSyntaxException: Could not parse expression `new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().class("android.widget.ImageView")).getChildByText(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.spotify.music:id/title"), "UnderCover")`: UiScrollable has no suitable constructor with arguments [new UiSelector().class("android.widget.ImageView")]
at io.appium.uiautomator2.utils.UiExpressionParser.findConstructor(UiExpressionParser.java:232)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Public Constructor for `UIScrollable` is:

```
UiScrollable(UiSelector container);
```

Use Public method `className` of `UiSelector` like:

```
UiSelector className (String className); //or UiSelector className (Class<T> type);
```

Try

```
new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.ImageView"));
```

instead of

```
new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().class("android.widget.ImageView"));
```

Refer official documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiSelector#classes

Comment: @shreyashshukla Glad to help. Could you please upvote the answer as useful. Thank you